# not able to ping through ssh tunnel device

Tags: ssh, networking, ip, ssh-tunneling, ping

I am trying to create an ssh VPN (through port 443) to bypass NAT and filtering.
I am using [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN) tutorial. The OS is Debian testing on both sides.

The tunnel devices are created on both sides, and addresses are assigned.

ssh command (as root on machine B): `ssh -w 0:0 MACHINE_A_PUBLIC_IP -p 443`

a shell opens for root

On the server (machine A), PermitTunnel is set to yes, and `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns `1`

machine A:

```
ip link set tun0 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.100/32 peer 10.0.0.200 dev tun0
```

machine B:

```
ip link set tun0 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.200/32 peer 10.0.0.100 dev tun0
```

result:

machine A:

```
36: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.0.0.100 peer 10.0.0.200/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9210:8322:2382:e696/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

machine B:

```
32: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.0.0.200 peer 10.0.0.100/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::bd70:5f4d:c8f5:aa2c/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Why can I not send pings?

Am I missing an obvious troubleshooting step?

Could it somehow be the filter that I am behind?

**edit:**

on machine A (server) `ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 proto static metric 100 
10.0.0.200 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.126 metric 100 
192.168.100.0/24 dev virbr1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.1 linkdown 
192.168.105.0/24 dev virbr4 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.105.1 linkdown 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 
239.0.0.0/8 dev lo scope link
```

on machine B (client) `ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto static metric 600 
10.0.0.100 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.200 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.136 metric 600
```

on machine B (client) `ping 10.0.0.100`:

```
PING 10.0.0.100 (10.0.0.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.0.0.100 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9000ms
```

the output of `ping` is the same on the server
they can each ping their own interfaces (machine B can ping 10.0.0.200), (machine A can ping 10.0.0.100)

Comment: Please post results of `ip route` and your attempted ping command.

Comment: Sorry about that, the post has been edited.

Comment: No worries. This is a bit strange, to say the least - I've been able to create a working tunnel without any problem, following those instructions. Maybe you could try running `tcpdump -i tun0` on another root terminal on both sides, while running ping? Then you could maybe see something interesting that you can share.

Comment: Ahhh, this is interesting. `tcpdump -i tun0` is showing the IMCP request as going to `10-0-0-100-static.midco.net` (midco is my isp) So the traffic must be going through the tunnel then to the internet? "Passing" the 10.0.0.100 machine?

Comment: I think that `10-0-0-100-static.midco.net` is an artifact of reverse DNS resolution and not useful - you can add `-n` flag to `tcpdump` to see plain IPs. The real question is whether packets go from A to B and can't find the way back for some reason, or they don't even reach B at all; to know that you need to run tcpdump on both sides. Also, try to ping the other way round. EDIT: output from `iptables -L` on both sides can also shed some light on this issue

Comment: Ahha the ping is getting to 10.0.0.100, and is replied to, but 10.0.0.200 is not getting it. pinging the other way shows that 10.0.0.200 is can't see it. So the traffic is not able to return to 10.0.0.200. Any suggestion as to why?

Answer (score 0):

In client ssh_config:

```
Tunnel point-to-point
```

In server sshd_config:

```
PermitTunnel point-to-point
```

Then establish the connection with one line on the client:

```
ssh \
  -o PermitLocalCommand=yes \
  -o LocalCommand="sudo ifconfig tun5 192.168.42.2 pointopoint 192.168.42.1 netmask 255.255.255.0" \
  -o ServerAliveInterval=60 \
  -w 5:5 root@192.168.1.109 \
  'sudo ifconfig tun5 192.168.42.1 pointopoint 192.168.42.2 netmask 255.255.255.0; echo tun5 ready'
```

You can terminate with ctr-c.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to ping 192.168.42.1 from 192.168.42.2.

Comment: then try another protocol, e.g. `telnet 192.168.42.1 443`

Comment: Nope, I also tried netcat and I tried scanning with nmap (192.168.1.42 has services running on it.).

Comment: Then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Are you using a custom kernel?

Comment: Nope, Debian testing and stock kernel (4.7.0.1) on both sides.

Comment: I'd also tested between two debians. One didn't work with my custom kernel. I have no more idea. It may be a testing release bug. Try with kernel of jessie. It may worth a try.

Comment: yep, I downgraded my kernel to 3.16.0-4 and it worked right away, re upgrading to 4.7.0-1 made the problem occur again.

Comment: So the moral is (again): don't try new things with testing releases.

Comment: I recommend to fill a bugreport for debian kernel developers. They might know why this occurs.

Comment: I'm having the same problem under `4.19.0-6-amd64`.